# Intuitive explanation for property of a function's derivative with respect to its parameters

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, intuition

Sorry for the very basic question, and thank you for the help.

If I have a function $c(a, b) = a * b$ and I take its derivative with respect to each of its parameters, it results in the other parameter's value:
$$ \frac{dc}{da}=b \hspace{2em} \frac{dc}{db}=a$$

For example, when $a=2$ and $b=3$, $\frac{dc}{da}=3$ and $\frac{dc}{db}=2$. This can be found through the [difference quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient).

My calculus is evidently not strong, but I am struggling to think of a logical, intuitive reason to explain this. I also do not know what this property is called, so it is difficult to just google it. Would anyone be able to offer any help in explaining this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need calculus to see that if $c = ab$ and you change $a$ by $h$ then $c$ changes by $bh$.

To connect it to calculus, think about the meaning of the derivative.
For a differentiable function $f$ if you change $x$ by $h$ you change $f(x)$ by *approximately* $f'(x)h$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Would you mind putting that in a real world example? I don't think I've ever thought of "if... you change a by h then c changes by bh" and am struggling to conceptualize the symbols' meanings.

Comment: Draw a rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$. Increase $a$ by $h$. What happens to the area $ab$?

Comment: That's the exact scenario I ended up using to help me reason through it. I think it was definitely the language of the formula that was messing me up because that relationship is very logical and straightforward. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

When you take the derivative of a multivariable function such as your $c(a,b) = ab$, you must specify which variable you are taking the derivative with respect to. This is called a *partial derivative*. If we take the the partial derivative $\frac{\partial c}{\partial b}$ of $ab$, then we treat all variables except $b$ as constant. This means we are basically taking the derivative of a function like $f(x) = ax$, where $a$ is constant. What is that derivative and what is your interpretation of it?